# Is there a way to send a blog post to wordpress via an api?

Tags: php, api, wordpress

In more details:
I want to build a web service to which users register and by browsing my site, users can send blog posts to their own blogs. Initially wordpress.org is discussed. However, I'll be happy to hear solutions for typepad or wordpress.com as well.

1. The ideal solution would be a way for my server to simply "tell" their blog what to post (as a draft of course for them to confirm).
2. A good solution would be for my users to install a plugin in their blog that will allow my server the above functionality.
3. Lacking any other solution, I would give my users text to copy-paste into their blog editor.

Help me find a solution and feel free to be creative!

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is an [XMLRPC](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support) interface.

You have to enable it in some config file if I remember well. Its been quite a while.

Answer (score 0):

yes wordpress supports such api. checkout windows live writer. http://windowslivewriter.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!D85741BB5E0BE8AA!174.entry